# Bash: Secure handling of user input

Tags: linux, bash, security

I have to process some user input in bash that may could contain harmful content. I have to do operations like this:

```
IFS=\; read -r -a values <<< "$badUserContent"
if ! [[ "${values[0]}" =~ $regex ]];.......
```

Is this a good idea? How can I secure my code?

Comment: Secure from what? You aren't using `eval` for anything, which is good.

Comment: Seems safe to me, unless you use `badUserContent` or `values` somewhere else.

Comment: @chepner but I'm passing the string as an "argument" to an other bash command? No chance to inject other commands here?

Comment: In the code you show, no. `read` will not evaluate the string, nor will the `=~` operator. (Unlike some languages, `bash` does not have a way to execute arbitrary code during a regular expression match.)